# How to select an aggregate root in EF .net

Tags: .net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I'm studying about DDD and doing some tests, I came across the following situation:

I have two aggregated entities:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFpxT.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed3Vg.png

According to DDD concepts, we cannot relate two aggregates directly, so in the Order entity I just created a buyer identifier called buyerid.

The relationship with the database of these two entities I created is as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXuiK.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vLMt.png

My doubt is the following: how would I make a query to bring the buyer's data with the order?

I tried some options like the below:

await _context.Orders.Include(o => o.BuyerId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

await _context.Orders.Include(x => _context.Buyers.Where(c => c.Id == x.BuyerId))                          .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

But I get this same error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQeKX.png

Comment: Start with the basics around navigation properties and EF before diving head-long into how to apply patterns like DDD:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: thanks for your reply, from what i read about ddd so far we use aggregates to define bounded contexts
I had a lot of doubts about when I need to relate these contexts in a query, for example, how would I do that? using EF's JOIN() function? because by DDD rules I can't place a navigation property linking one aggregate to another or am I wrong in this statement?

Comment: Bounded contexts for aggregates is perfectly fine, but that context should serve the entire needs of the aggregage, so all children and references, not crossing concerns between DbContexts. This can mean that entities are registered with more than one DbContext.  What you really want to avoid is things like Generic patterns around entities, especially with aggregate designs.

Answer (score 0):

My doubt would be that since I don't have navigation entities between the aggregates, how would I make a query bringing the data together if necessary, in my tests so far I've managed with the following code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmDLD.png